# update only from's visible fields if parent model doesn't exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have django model inherited from User:

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(User):
  birth_date = models.DateField()
  bio = models.TextField(null=True)
  ...
```

**forms.py**:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
  birth_date = forms.DateField()
  class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date', 'bio')
```

So I have 2 tables in database:

- auth_user (id, username, first_name, last_name, ...)
- user_profile(birth_date, bio, user_ptr_id) 
  with `one to one` relationship.

I need to update or create (if they didn't exist) only raws specified in my form. That with SQL would look like:

```sql
UPDATE auth_user 
SET first_name=form_first_name, last_name=form_last_name
WHERE id = request.user.id

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE user_ptr_id = request.id)
  UPDATE user_profile 
  SET (birth_date = form_birth_date, bio = form_bio)
  WHERE user_ptr_id=request.id
ELSE
  INSERT INTO user_profile (user_ptr_id, birth_date, bio)
  VALUES (request.user.id, form_birth_date, form_bio )
```

Which theoretically should look like:

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user_profile)
```

But it will throw an exception if there's no raw in database. Is there a way to acomplish it? Or I just need to do multiple checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right you should be using get_or_create ([see docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/))

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(pk=request.user.id)
```

Furthermore you need to derive from AbstractBaseUser instead of User.

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
       birth_date = models.DateField()
       ....
```

See the docu for [Specifying a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/).

Comment: Somehow if User raw exists, but UserProfile raw doesn't exist it throws {IntegrityError}UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Comment: Thanks, having 1 table (UserProfile, which has been set to AUTH_USER_MODEL) instead of two (UserProfile->User)  solved the problem. Just out of curiosity lets imagine the situation where I have a custom inheritance ModelA(ModelB) instead of UserProfile(user). Is there a way to acomplish the goal specified in my question?

Comment: If you have a ModelA(ModelB) inheritance there will be absolutely no  logical connection between your instances of A and B. This is not a OnetoOne relationship (for this you would have a field my_relative_in_B=models.OneToOneField(B) in the A-model)!

Comment: Yep truly so. For example I have ModelB[fieldb1, fieldb2] and ModelA[fielda1, fielda2](ModelB). So ModelA has total 4 fields, coz 2 of them are inhertited from ModelB. And I want to create FormA which provides editing those 4 fields.  And now I have the situation where rowB already exists in tableB, but rowA from modelA doesn't. So I display a form in my template with those 2 already existed fields (from ModelB) and 2 blank fileds(from modelA).  User adds fielda1 to form and posts form to save. How do I tell  formA to handle it? (what if I have 3+ level inheritance)